# Passing a variable with send_keys() to an alert confirmation popup

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, popup, prompt

I have an error with selenium and passing a variable with send_keys() to an alert confirmation popup. Here's the code simplified (a1 and a2 are integer variables)

```
av=int((a1+a2)/2)
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('web')
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("SinglesthroughputOverrides1")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys(int(av))
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
driver.switch_to.alert.send_keys(int(av))
```

and I'm getting the following error on the last line

> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

When I try to pass on a certain string with driver.switch_to.alert.send_keys("abcd") it works perfectly.

Can someone explain me why it's working on the first send_keys and not on the second one?

Comment: `driver.switch_to.alert.send_keys(str(av))` try this

Answer (score 0):

Convert the integer `int(av)` into a string while invoking `send_keys()` as follows:

```
driver.switch_to.alert.send_keys(str(int(av)))
```